# How to Redirect webpage to different webpage after submitting form elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a webpage where I need to use radio buttons as form elements. Please check the code below...

```
<form action="glitter.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/>
<input type="radio" name="font1" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/> 
<input type="radio" name="font2" value="fonts/darkcrystalout2.ttf"/> 
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The above code works fine by submitting the radio button values to "glitter.php", but what I need is for values to first be submitted to "glitter.php". After submission, the webpage should be redirected to another web page (ex: "kothi.html"). Is there a way to do this by using PHP or JQuery. Please help me fix this problem....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `header("location: http://domainname/path/to/kothi.html");`

**[Find the manual here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)**

Comment: Use links for links and code for code, I've edited for you, see what I did and try to do it yourself next time :)

Comment: Hi poonam can you brief me with that .. where do we use that cade????it should in header tag or within form body or is it function..can you please compleate the code???

Comment: I am assuming your kothi.html file is present in your working directory(no nested directory) and your folder name is test then your code will be header("Location : http://localhost/test/kothi.php"); this code will come at the place where you want to redirect your page

Comment: thanks alot for every one who replied for my question.... yes code works fine if iam using php webpage.. but what if iam using "html" page ..i tried to add     <?php

{
// Do you stuff then redirect
header("location: http://mydomain.com/kothi.html");
}
?> it in header but no go...

Comment: header("location: mydomain.com/kothi.html"); 
have you received any error?
is their any space before opening <?php tag or any echo or html then it will through an error and will not redirect

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .... as i have told you iam using the code in html page  .... so adding the code in between <head> <?php
{
header("location: http://mydomainpath/kothi.html");
}
?></head> do i have to add the code with <form> </form> ... i have not got any error code after submitting it is redirecting to "glitter.php"

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .... as i have told you iam using the code in html page  .... so adding the code in between <head> <?php
{
header("location: http://mydomainpath/kothi.html");
}
?></head> do i have to add the code with <form> </form> ... i have not got any error code after submitting it is redirecting to "glitter.php"

Comment: before starting any html or doctype use <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['formsubmit'])){header("location:......");}?>
and name your submit button as formssubmit then it should have been work

Comment: Hello poonam i really appreciate the way you are trying to help me... but its not working Iam extremely sorry may be iam doing some mistakes .....please check the compleate code below...

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){header("location:  http://domainpath/kothi.html");}?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="glitter.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/>
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>
   <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down">
</form> 
</body>
<html>

Comment: syntax error I found header("location: domainpath/kothi.html";);
replace it with header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");

Comment: hi Poonam  i had corrected sytax error before posting .....<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){header("header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");}?>
<html> <body> 
<form action="glitter.php" method="post">  
<input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/>  
<input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>  
<input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> 
</form>

</body> 
</html> tried almost all possibilities.. :{ but still not working..any other ways???

Answer (score 2):

You want to redirect it using PHP's `header()` function, to send a `Location` header (on glitter.php, after all the form processing).

```
header("Location: /kothi.html"); //Assuming kothi.html is 
                                 //found on the root of the website.
die();                           //Stop processing
```

Also, if you want your radio buttons to actually work, you need to give them all the same name (otherwise they won't group)

```
<form action="glitter.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/>
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout2.ttf"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

// Glitter.php page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['font']))
{
// Do you stuff then redirect
header("location: yourPage.html");
// adding exit() thanks to MrJ

exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Remember to also add `exit();` after `header("location: yourPage.html");` to stop the rest of the page from loading

Answer (score 0):

```
header("location: http://domainname/path/to/kothi.html");
```

OR

```
header("location: ./kothi.html");
```

would both work.

Comment: hello truth ,,please check the compleate code below... <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){header("location: domainpath/kothi.html";);}?> <html> <body> <form action="glitter.php" method="post">  <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/>  <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>  <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> </form> </body> <html> anything wrong????

Answer (score 0):

We'll use Ajax to do this. First, we'll grab the form and we'll stop the default action with e.preventDefault();. Then we'll grab the value of the form. with jQuery's robust $.ajax method, we set the url to our glitter.php file, our data is sent as a query string, so, 'mysite.com/?val=OurValue. Our value is the value of 'val', which is whatever is our form submitted. The success function allows us to direct the page only after the form has been successfully submitted. top.location.href allows us to perform a standard redirect to wherever we want, locally, or externally. I left 'response' in the success function so you can dictate what to do and when to do it.

Hope this helps.

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  val = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'glitter.php',
    data: 'val='+val,
    success: function(data, response){
      top.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

How about adding an "action" to your form?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand but there is already an action in the form, action="glitter.php" !